# How to run (and debug) the xmrig project on my Windows machine

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++.

I've cloned the project to my `Visual Studio 2017\Projects\`

what's next?

Visual Studio 2017 doesn't recognize the project.

How can I build?

How can I debug?

Thank you.